# $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \exists v \in V$ so that $x - \varepsilon < v$ if and only if $x = \sup V$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

I'm trying to prove that, given a non-empty bounded set $V$ so that $V \subset \mathbb{R}$ that an upperbound
$x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a supremum of V if and only if $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \exists v \in V$ so that $x - \varepsilon  < v$

I've already proven that 
$x = \sup V$ implies $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \exists v \in V$ so that $x - \varepsilon  < v$

but I'm stuck on the reverse. I've tried to proof it by contradiction, but I'm not really getting anywhere. I get that, if we assume $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \exists v \in V$ so that $x - \varepsilon  < v$  and that $x \neq \sup V$ we must accept that there exists an $y \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $y = \sup V$ Considering all non-empty bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ have a subset. But I'm not really getting anywhere further. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your statement is incomplete. The $\forall\epsilon\dots$ is also true for any $x\in V$. You should add the condition that $x$ is an upper bound for the elements of $V$.

Comment: @SMoore thanks! I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x = \sup V$

By definition $x$ is the smallest upper bound of $V$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Suppose that there is no $v$ such that $x-\epsilon<v$, this implies that $\forall v,x-\epsilon\ge v$, thus $x-\epsilon$ is an upper bound of $V$ smaller than $x$, which is impossible.

Hence $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \exists v \in V,x-\epsilon<v$

---

Edit : my bad, you wanted the other way. Here it is :

We have $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \exists v \in V,x-\epsilon<v$.

Let $x'=\sup V$.

- If $x'<x$, then by definition this is absurd by choosing $\epsilon<x-x'$
- If $x'>x$, then $x$ is an upperbound of $V$ smaller than $x'$ which is impossible

Hence $x=\sup V$

Comment: actually he said he already proved this. He is stuck on the reverse.

Comment: @SiXUlm Oh my bad I read it too fast. I'll edit it.

Comment: @pokemanfan I edited it, now it's the right way

Comment: I did a few minutes after I commented.  So, no, I hadn't seen it and that was what I was overlooking.